# Uploading the csv in react hooks gives a blank array in console

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, papaparse

In a react hooks page, while uploading the csv file I am getting a blank array, could someone please advise how can display the contents of `Name`, `E-mail 1 - Value` column only in the screen.

```
const ManageNominees = () => {

    const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState([]);

    const csvFile = "C:/Users/Project/contacts.csv";
    const onChange = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        setCsvData({ ...csvData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const importCSV = () => {
        Papa.parse(csvFile, {
          complete: updateData,
          header: true
        });
      };

    const updateData = (result) => {
        var data = result.data;
        console.log(data);
      }

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Upload Data</h1>
        <input
          className="CSVData"
          type="file"
          name="file"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <button onClick={importCSV}>Upload CSV</button>
    </div>
 )
}

export default ManageNominees
```

Answer (score 0):

Your csvFile variable is just a string that is a path to file. Before feeding it to papaParser you need to actually read file content.

```
const readFileContent = file =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    fileReader.onload = e => resolve(fileReader.result);
    fileReader.onerror = () => reject('something went wrong');
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  });
```

and then in your onChange in input:

```
const onChange = (e) => { 
const file = event.target.files[0];
const content = await readFileContent(file);
Papa.parse(content, {
          complete: updateData,
          header: true
        });
}
```

Comment: I am getting error like ``Unexpected reserved word 'await'.```

Comment: Ì have removed await and now getting another error ``TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.``

Comment: You have to put await back and put await in front of onChange as well.